# Save Positive Numbers in parentheses in csv

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv

I want to save the positive numbers in parentheses in .csv. For example:

```
 My number = (0.235)
```

When I try to use number format, it automatically converts this number to -0.235. I changed the format, use text format and then it works. However, once I save and re-open the data it again converts to -0.235. I should save it in .csv format. Any advice?

Comment: As far as I can see there is no way around this. Excel dutifully saves the file with `(0.235)` directly to the CSV and will open it back up as a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Format -> Cells -> Custom - add new with.. `(0);-0`.

- Then save as normal Excel.
- If you save as CSV - then open it in Notepad or TextEdit you will see the parentheses and minus sign are saved.
- But when re-opening it in Excel it reconverts it back to -1/1 etc losing your parentheses.
- Best to use Excel format when saving to preserve the formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not when you save it in CSV (assuming you converted to text format as you mention above; or use a custom number format like that shown by @JGFMK).  The problem is when you open it in Excel.

As is usually the case, in order to prevent Excel from doing automatic conversions, you need to **IMPORT** the csv file and not **OPEN** it.  You will then have the opportunity to designate that column as **TEXT**, and your parentheses will be preserved.

When you are dealing with any CSV file, formatting is not included. So Excel tries to interpret the values as best it can (as if you were typing the value into a cell manually).  This can cause issues not only with your circumstance, but also with certain fractions, ratios, dates not in the format of the computer system, etc.  For all these reasons, you are often best off importing rather than opening any csv file in Excel.